# Python: Rabin-Karp algorithm hashing

Tags: python, string, algorithm, pattern-matching

I am implementing Rabin-Karp algorithm for fun. I came across this pseudocode:

```
    RABIN -KARP -MATCHER (T, P, d, q)
    1 n = T.length
    2 m = P.length
    3 h = d^(m-1) mod q
    4 p=0
    5 t= 0
    6 for i = 1 to m
    / preprocessing
    /
    7 p = (dp + P [i]) mod q
    8 t = (dt + T [i]) mod q
    9 for s = 0 to n-m
    / matching
    /
    10     if p == t
    11         if P [1... m] == T [s + 1...s + m]
    12             print “Pattern occurs with shift” s
    13     if s < n-m
    14         t  = (d(t-T[s + 1]h) + T [s + m + 1]) mod q
```

I implemented in Python 2.7 like so:

```
def Rabin_Karp_Matcher(text, pattern, d, q):
    n = len(text)
    m = len(pattern)
    h = pow(d,m-1)%q
    p = 0
    t =0
    result = []
    for i in range(m): # preprocessing
        p = (d*p+ord(pattern[i]))%q
        t = (d*t+ord(text[i]))%q
    for s in range(n-m):
        if p == t: # check character by character
            match = True
            for i in range(m):
                if pattern[i] != text[s+i]:
                    match = False
                    break
            if match:
                result = result + [s]
        if s < n-m:
                t = (d*(t-ord(text[s+1])*h)+ord(text[s+m]))%q #index out of bounds here
    return result
```

where result is a list containing the index in text of pattern.

My code is failing to find the 26 in 3141592653589793
 and I suspect it has something to do with my hashcode defined by line 14 of the pseudocode. Can anyone please help with this.

I passed in the following paramters:

P = "26"
T = "3141592653589793"
d = 257
q = 11

P and T must be strings/arrays of chars

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
def Rabin_Karp_Matcher(text, pattern, d, q):
    n = len(text)
    m = len(pattern)
    h = pow(d,m-1)%q
    p = 0
    t = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(m): # preprocessing
        p = (d*p+ord(pattern[i]))%q
        t = (d*t+ord(text[i]))%q
    for s in range(n-m+1): # note the +1
        if p == t: # check character by character
            match = True
            for i in range(m):
                if pattern[i] != text[s+i]:
                    match = False
                    break
            if match:
                result = result + [s]
        if s < n-m:
            t = (t-h*ord(text[s]))%q # remove letter s
            t = (t*d+ord(text[s+m]))%q # add letter s+m
            t = (t+q)%q # make sure that t >= 0
    return result
print (Rabin_Karp_Matcher ("3141592653589793", "26", 257, 11))
print (Rabin_Karp_Matcher ("xxxxx", "xx", 40999999, 999999937))
```

The output is:

```
[6]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

On the first step, you check whether `text[0..m] == pattern`. On the second step, you want to check whether `text[1..m+1] == pattern`. Thus you remove `text[0]` from the hash (at the moment it is multiplied by your precomputed `h`): `t = (t-h*ord(text[s]))%q`. And then, add `text[m]` to it: `t = (t*d+ord(text[s+m]))%q`. On the next step, you remove `text[1]` and add `text[m+1]`, and so on. The `t = (t+q)%q` line is there because a negative number modulo `q` yields remainder in the range `(-q; 0]`, and we want it to be in the range `[0; q)`.

Note that you want to check a total of `n-m+1` substrings, not `n-m`, hence the correct loop is `for s in range(n-m+1)`. Checked by the second example (finding "xx" in "xxxxx").

Also worth noting:

1. The line `h = pow(d,m-1)%q` may be too slow if `m` is large. It is better to take the result modulo `q` after each of the `m-2` multiplications. Or just use the built-in way: `h = pow(d,m-1,q)`, as suggested by @oBrstisf8o in the comments.
2. This algorithm is still O(nm) in the worst case. With `text="a"*100000` and `pattern="a"*50000`, it will find 50001 positions where a substring of text matches the pattern, and it will check them all character-by-character. If you expect your code to work fast in such extreme cases, you should skip the character-by-character comparison and find a way to deal with false positives (i.e., hashes are equal but strings are not). Picking a large prime number `q` may help reduce the probability of a false positive to an acceptable level.

Comment: So, there IS an error in pseudo-code, right? With missing module in hash calculation. Because it is from the Kormen Algorithms book and it is so strange that there's an error there, I've spent some time trying to find error in my code or understanding and from what I can see - there's an error in the formula itself.

Comment: I'm late, but to note that python now has (no clue since when) a ``pow(num, exp, modulo)`` function, which is faster than ``pow(num, exp) % modulo``.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer is that you need to indent the "for s" loop:

```
def Rabin_Karp_Matcher(text, pattern, d, q):
    n = len(text)
    m = len(pattern)
    h = pow(d,m-1)%q
    p = 0
    t =0
    result = []
    for i in range(m): # preprocessing
        p = (d*p+ord(pattern[i]))%q
        t = (d*t+ord(text[i]))%q

        for s in range(n-m):
            if p == t: # check character by character
                match = True
                for i in range(m):
                    if pattern[i] != text[s+i]:
                        match = False
                        break
                if match:
                    result = result + [s]
            if s < n-m:
                    t = (d*(t-ord(text[s+1])*h)+ord(text[s+m]))%q #index out of bounds here


    return result
```

This gives me the answer 6, which is what you are looking for I imagine.  Interesting algorithm man.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However I believe that is a one-off/lucky that it gave the correct output. Please see revised pseudo code with correct indentation. Also, I plugged in different values in for P and this does not yield the correct result. Also, I am expecting a list of indices not just the first occurrence. I am certain the error is in the hash code in line 14 I just cannot decipher what that part is doing.

Comment: @SeekingAlpha Oh hey no worries, I was happy to 'help' even if I was wrong :)