# How to search pattern after found a pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Find the value after "key :" based on  "c :"

The file.txt contain

c : abc  eas key : 123
c : abg  ded key : 345
c : bbs  eds key : 567
c : def  eas key : 565

User input bss and get output 567

Here the code that I already tried

```
def Rabin_Karp(text, pattern, d, q):
    n = len(text)
    m = len(pattern)
    h = pow(d,m-1)%q
    p = 0
    t = 0
    result = []
    for i in range(m):
        p = (d*p+ord(pattern[i]))%q
        t = (d*t+ord(text[i]))%q
    for s in range(n-m+1):
        if p == t:
            match = True
            for i in range(m):
                if pattern[i] != text[s+i]:
                    match = False
                    break
            if match:
                result = result + [s]

        if s < n-m:
            t = (t-h*ord(text[s]))%q
            t = (t*d+ord(text[s+m]))%q
            t = (t+q)%q
    return result

log = open(r"file.txt", encoding="utf8")
print (Rabin_Karp(file.read(), "bbs", 257, 11))
```

I dont know how to make it continue to search for the key

*the Rabin_Karp code I copy it from here [Python: Rabin-Karp algorithm hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216948/python-rabin-karp-algorithm-hashing)

Comment: See “How to ask and answer a homework question”: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I already tried to show all my work but its too mess to explain. you can see it in edit history.

Comment: you should atleast keep the code. it will be more understandable

Comment: @NikkoBobier done edit

Comment: is the format of each line in the text always `c : key1 key2 key3 : 565` ?